# Setting state using React hooks does not work correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a component in which I'm setting state

```
const LIMIT_MOBILE = 3;
const LIMIT_WEB = 6;
const isMobile = useMediaQuery(MOBILE_BREAKPOINT);
const initialLimit = isMobile ? LIMIT_MOBILE : LIMIT_WEB;
const [limit, setLimit] = useState(initialLimit);
```

After component has mounted the state is set always to 6 on mobile which is not correct. `initialLimit` is set to 3 after couple of ms or after interaction inside the app. Any idea where the problem might be ?

Edit: useMediaQuery is from material-ui

Comment: add the rest of the code including the value of `MOBILE_BREAKPOINT`

Comment: Probably inside the Hook, check its implementation.

Comment: Please share the codesandbox link for us to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch for changes of the isMobile value and set it afterwards:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setLimit(isMobile ? LIMIT_MOBILE : LIMIT_WEB);
}, [isMobile])
```

This is because the useMediaQuery hook itself has to compute your media query and then give you the result (by that time the initial value of your useState has already been set).

The default value (which is returned initially) of useMediaQuery is null and it coerces to false (hence the wrong initial limit).

Comment: The [isMobile] part was hard to get as I have always used the second parameter as an empty array to mimic the behaviour of componentDidUpdate. Thank you